# Custom adapter notifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I tried to call `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` but it doesn't work at all. How can I refresh the list?

```
public class CarListMenu extends Fragment{


    public CarListAdapter adapter= null;
    static ArrayList<carArrayItem> CarPriceItem ;
    private static ListView CarListView;



     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            CarListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.car_price_list_menu, container, false);

            CarPriceItem.add(new carArrayItem("No","No","NO","NO" , "NO"));

            adapter = new CarListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),CarPriceItem);
            CarListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return CarListView;
        }

     public static class App extends Application{

            private static Context mContext;

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
                mContext = this;
            }

            public static Context getContext(){
                return mContext;
            }
        }


public static void change(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultback){



    CarPriceItem = new ArrayList<carArrayItem>();
    //CarPriceItem.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < (resultback.size()); i+=6) {

        CarPriceItem.add(new carArrayItem((resultback.get(i).get("table").toString()),
                (resultback.get(i+1).get("table").toString()),
                (resultback.get(i+2).get("table").toString()), 
                (resultback.get(i+3).get("table").toString()), 
                (resultback.get(i+5).get("table").toString())));

        }

    CarListAdapter adapter =  new CarListAdapter(App.getContext(),CarPriceItem);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } 




}
class CarListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<carArrayItem> CarPriceItem = new ArrayList<carArrayItem>();

    public CarListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<carArrayItem> CarPriceItem){
        this.context = context;
        this.CarPriceItem = CarPriceItem;

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CarPriceItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return CarPriceItem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.car_list_item, null);
        }


        TextView CarmodelName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CarModel);
        TextView MarketP = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MarketPriceData);
        TextView ResellerP = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ResellerPricesData);
        TextView Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DescriptionData);
        TextView LastUpdate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LastUpdateData);


        CarmodelName.setText(CarPriceItem.get(position).getCarname());
        MarketP.setText(CarPriceItem.get(position).getMarketPrice());
        ResellerP.setText(CarPriceItem.get(position).getResellerPrice());
        Description.setText(CarPriceItem.get(position).getDescription());
        LastUpdate.setText(CarPriceItem.get(position).getUpdateTime());



        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Comment: Try to stick to the usual java naming conventions if you want others to look at your code. Class names like `carArrayItem` UpperCamelCase, variables like `CarPriceItem` lowerCamelCase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Final code: It works fine. thanks to @Justin Powell

```
public static void change(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultback){

    ArrayList<carArrayItem> CarPriceItemnew = new ArrayList<carArrayItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < (resultback.size()); i+=6) {

            CarPriceItemnew.add(new carArrayItem((resultback.get(i).get("table").toString()),
            (resultback.get(i+1).get("table").toString()),
            (resultback.get(i+2).get("table").toString()), 
            (resultback.get(i+3).get("table").toString()), 
            (resultback.get(i+5).get("table").toString())));

    }

    CarPriceItem.clear();
    CarPriceItem.addAll(CarPriceItemnew);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new adapter in `change()`, but you aren't assigning it to the ListView. You need to do one of two things:

1. Either assign the new adapter to your ListView using `CarListView.setAdapter(adapter);` in your `change()` method, or
2. Update the data in your adapter *without recreating it*. Then you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the list.

Comment: I tried first one , it doesn't work.
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference


for second one: would you please explain more? i can't get it.
thanks

Comment: That means your ListView reference is null at that point in your code. When/where are you calling `change()`?

Answer (score 1):

Tested and perfectly working code is given below,

Create a Function in adapter like,

```
public void notify(ArrayList<String> list){
        this.list= list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and call the function from Activity whenever you have to notify.

```
adapter.notify(list);
```